# How to fix Xcode error "Invalid redeclaration" when using the same class name in different targets?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have an Xcode SwiftUI project where I want to have a macOS and iOS app. In one specific part of the app, I want to use SwiftUI `Image`. In SwiftUI, On macOS it's `Image(nsImage: )` and on iOS it's `Image(uiImage: )`. However, the class it's being used in is called `Settings`, so rather than using `#if os(iOS)`, I thought I'd create macOS and iOS targets, use different files, but those files have the same class name. The idea is that each file would be in a different target, so Xcode should only compile the file for that target. However, Xcode is giving me errors that I'm getting a class redeclaration. Why? If the files are in different targets, why does Xcode care about the file that's NOT in the selected target?

Here's my minimal example:

```
struct TargetTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, when you create a SwiftUI project, Xcode creates a file and class called `ContentView`. Inside that class is a `Text` that says "Hello world". I changed it to say "Hello Mac".

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, Mac!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

So, I created a target called "TargetTestApp-iOS" and duplicated the `ContentView` file, and called it `ContentView-iOS.swift`. This is the contents:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, Phone!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

The idea is that when `ContentView()` is called from `TargetTestApp`, the compiler should only compile in files attached to the current target, but it's not - it's pulling in BOTH files. So when I build the macOS target, `ContentView` should only reference the macOS file, and the iOS target build should exclude the macOS file and include the iOS target. Xcode doesn't seem to be doing that.

`ContentView-iOS.swift` is NOT part of the macOS target, only a member of the iOS target:

[image]

And here's the membership of the macOS file. Note that it's ONLY a part of the macOS target:

[image]

So why is Xcode telling me that there's an invalid redeclaration when it shouldn't be looking at the files that aren't part of the current target? Isn't the whole POINT of the target system to include/exclude files?

Any help would be appreciated because I am really trying to avoid using `#if(os)`.

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted this, I walked away for a sec and thought about "Compile Sources". Sure enough, Xcode pulled in the wrong files for the selected target. The iOS target was correct, but the macOS target pulled in the iOS file, so that target had the macOS and iOS targets. I removed the iOS file from "Compile Sources" and now it works.

Bug in Xcode?

Comment: Downvoting something which is clearly a bug in Xcode is pretty cowardly. Also shows how broken the system is.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't understand this answer. What do you mean by "Xcode pulled in the wrong files"? please clarify why do you think Xcode has a bug? From how I see it, you are in charge of adding files to the right target, so seems you added them by mistake? or more likely you didn't check to which target Xcode added them by default, which is usually the same target(s) as the previous file you added.

Comment: When you tick a target for a file off, Xcode is supposed to remove that file from "Compile Sources". It didn't. That's the bug. It does work most of the time (I've been testing it all day), but Xcode can get into a state where if you tick a file's target off or on, "Compile Sources" isn't modified. That's the bug.

Comment: Same problem. And yes there are redundant files in "Compile Sources". I created the project with one multi-platform target and then split it to two separated targets.